# How can I append the values of a list to the values of a DataFrame column using Python?

Tags: python

I have this DataFrame:

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_items([('id', [14, 49, 21]), 
                     ('parameter', [12, 23, 11])])
```

And I have this list:

```
[8, 1, 3]
<class 'list'>
```

I want to append the list values to each value of the column id of the dataframe df, I want something like this:

```
   id       parameter
0  148         12
1  491         23
2  213         11
```

How can I do it?

Comment: It may be worth specifying how you want the 'append' the values to the column to work, in this case the number is just added on as if they were strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `zip` works:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('id', [14, 49, 21]), ('parameter', [12, 23, 11])])
l = [8, 1, 3]
df['id'] = [int(''.join([str(j) for j in i])) for i in zip(df['id'], l)]
```

and the resulting `df` is:

```
>>> df
    id  parameter
0  148         12
1  491         23
2  213         11
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like so:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('id', [14, 49, 21]), ('parameter', [12, 23, 11])])
l = iter([8, 1, 3])

df.id = df.id.apply(lambda x: str(x)+str(next(l))).astype(int)
print df
```

Output:

```
    id  parameter
0  148         12
1  491         23
2  213         11
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('id', [14, 49, 21]), ('parameter', [12, 23, 11])])

lista = [8,1,3]

for i in range(len(lista)):
    df['id'][i] = int(str(df['id'][i]) + str(lista[i]))

print df

   id  parameter
0  148         12
1  491         23
2  213         11
```